# my program says compiler errors after grading in gitbash

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

I'm writing a Java program in which I have to get the turtle to move West, east, north and south but what I have so far isn't getting the turtle to move in the desired direction.

```
public class Assignment7 {
    // TODO - you need to implement this. Move the given turtle to the West, n times
    public static void moveTurtleWest(Turtle t, int n)
    {

    }

    // TODO - you need to implement this. Move the given turtle to the East, n times
    public static void moveTurtleEast(Turtle t, int n)
    {
        for(int i=0; i <n;i++ ){ 
        t.moveEast();
    }

    // TODO - you need to implement this. Move the given turtle to the North, n times
    public static void moveTurtleNorth(Turtle t, int n)
    {
        for(int i=0; i <n;i++ ){ 
        t.moveNorth();
    }

    // TODO - you need to implement this. Move the given turtle to the South, n times
    public static void moveTurtleSouth(Turtle t, int n)
    {
        for(int i=0; i <n;i++ ){ 
        t.moveSouth(); 
    }

    // TODO - you need to implement this. Move the turtle to the asked position, by calling MoveXXX etc
    public static void moveTurtleTo(Turtle t, int x, int y)
    {
        moveTurtleTo(turtle.xPos,turtle.yPos);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // you can use this as you wish to test or exercise your function. Not graded.
        Turtle t=new Turtle();
        moveTurtleTo(t,15,16);
        System.out.println(t);  
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you having a moveTurtleTo() method inside a method also named moveTurtleTo()? show your overloaded method and show the Turtle class

Comment: compiler errors are different from undesired behavior. Could you please post the compiling errors ?

Comment: how is it suppose to be please?

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.684 secs

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're fishing for something like:

```
public class Assignment7 {

    public static void moveTurtleWest(Turtle t, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
            t.moveWest();
        }
    }

    public static void moveTurtleEast(Turtle t, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
            t.moveEast();
        }
    }

    public static void moveTurtleNorth(Turtle t, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
            t.moveNorth();
        }
    }

    public static void moveTurtleSouth(Turtle t, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
            t.moveSouth();
        }
    }

    public static void moveTurtleTo(Turtle t, int x, int y)
    {
        int delta_x = x - turtle.xPos;
        int delta_y = y - turtle.yPos;

        if (delta_x > 0) {
            moveTurtleEast(t, delta_x);
        } else if (delta_x < 0) {
            moveTurtleWest(t, -delta_x);
        }

        if (delta_y > 0) {
            moveTurtleNorth(t, delta_x);
        } else if (delta_y < 0) {
            moveTurtleSouth(t, -delta_x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Turtle t = new Turtle();

        moveTurtleTo(t, 15, 16);
    }
}
```

Be clear about your situation when posting to SO and you'll likely get a better answer faster.